# Can i create more than one signature .pcf file?

Tags: guidewire

I tried to create more than one signature in my .pcf file for Exitpoint, it showing an error. 
Is it acceptable, then what is default signature if not mentioned explicitly

Comment: Hi @m.kokhila, what error are you getting?

Comment: Hello OP, could you mark the answer from Umanath as the correct answer if that solution worked for your problem, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can add more than one Signature in LocationEntryPoint tab 
**Sample code**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<PCF
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../../pcf.xsd">
    <Forward
        canVisit="true"
        id="YourPageForward">
        <LocationEntryPoint
            signature="YourPageForward(queryParamId1:String)"/>
        <LocationEntryPoint
            signature="YourPageForward(queryParamId1:String, queryParamId2:String)"/>
        <Variable
            name="queryParamId1"
            type="String"/>
        <Variable
            name="queryParamId2"
            type="String"/>
        <ForwardCondition
            action="my.web.YourPageForwardHandler.Instance.doProcessOne(queryParamId1)"/>
        <ForwardCondition
            action="my.web.YourPageForwardHandler.Instance.doProcessTow(queryParamId1, queryParamId2)"/>   
    </Forward>
</PCF>
```